# How do I delete a row in Pandas dataframe when a specific column contains a value that signals to me that the row should be deleted?

Tags: python, pandas

Very simple question everyone, but nearly impossible to find answers to basic questions in official documentation.

I have a dataframe object in Pandas that has rows and columns.

One of the columns, named "CBSM", contains boolean values. I need to delete all rows from the dataframe where the value of the CBSM column = "Y".

I see that there is a method called `dataframe.drop()`

Label, Axis, and Level are 3 parameters that the `drop()` method takes in. I have no clue what values to provide these parameters to accomplish my need of deleting the rows in the fashion I described above. I have a feeling the `drop()` method is not the right way to do what I want.

Please advise, thanks.

Comment: @jezrael Thank you so much! Especially the quick answer and thorough sample breakdown. You are AWESOME!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method is called [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).

You can try [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
df.loc[~df['CBSM'].str.contains('Y')]
```

Sample:

```
print df
   A CBSM  L
0  1    Y  4
1  1    N  6
2  2    N  3

print df['CBSM'].str.contains('Y')
0     True
1    False
2    False
Name: CBSM, dtype: bool

#inverted boolean serie
print ~df['CBSM'].str.contains('Y')
0    False
1     True
2     True
Name: CBSM, dtype: bool

print df.loc[~df['CBSM'].str.contains('Y')] 
   A CBSM  L
1  1    N  6
2  2    N  3
```

Or:

```
print df.loc[~(df['CBSM'] == 'Y')] 
   A CBSM  L
1  1    N  6
2  2    N  3
```